# Protecting server data sent over network

Tags: c#, networking, encryption, authorization, client-server

I have two applications :

- A client that offers a user-friendly interface
- A server that takes care of all the actual functionalities of the client.

The person that uses my application uses the client obviously, while the server application is stationed on a server computer, the two applications communicate using the TCP.

I've got some premium functions in my client application that the person can only use if they pay a monthly fee by logging in.

Now, my question is the following:
How can I prevent that a person downloads the client application, pays a one-month fee just to check what TCP packet the server sends to the client so that then create their own application to just send that response over and over to the client to bypass logging in?

Is there any way to prevent the data that the server sends to the client from being read by the person running the client? Some kind of encryption?

Comment: Are you using any kind of encryption techniques?

Comment: None yet.. should I ? I thought encryption was only used to stop eavesdropping.

Comment: I think it'll be helpful in your case. An unauthorized person won't know the encryption technique, or the key to decrypt it. So he won't be able to generate the response correctly.

Comment: But if the client has to decrpyt it.. sending the encrypted data that the user _does_ have access to will still turn out the same right? the client will just decrypt it and read it as a valid login response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is authentication and authorization. The user has to log in with a password or something similar to prove its identity and then you can decide if the user paid the fee and is therefore authorized to use the premium functions. If the request is from an unauthorized user just respond with an error. Encryption is not really required but it is obviously a good idea to encrypt all the traffic, especially because you also transmitting authentication information. The easiest solution is to just use TLS.

Comment: How would the client know that the login response is not authorized? I mean.. it's a response from the server ( that's what the client thinks ) after all.. should I program my client to not trust the server then ?

Comment: I assumed the premium functionality relies on some server functionality - in that case it is sufficient that the server refuses to do its part. Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: Now that you said that, I feel stupid...
I can just deny the client's request on the server then like you said.. thanks :)

Comment: The thing is, you have zero control over what happens on the client. The user can always just decompile, modify and recompile the client, you can only make this an unpleasant thing to do but not prevent it. Or users could theoretically just develop an alternative client and then you loose any control. What can not be prevented on the server can not be prevented at all, at least almost always.